# How to overcome this xaml parse exception error?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

I'm doing this Windows Phone application sample and after creating a listbox inside a stackpanel everything was ok. But after sometime I get this error :

[image]

Below is the code for listbox I created in stackpanel :

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0"
         Name="listBox1">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
              Margin="0,0,17,0">
    <Image Source="icons/star.png"
           Height="100"
           Width="100"
           Margin="12,0,9,0">
    </Image>
    <StackPanel Width="311">
      <TextBlock Text="Folders"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text="my personal images"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Margin="12,-6,12,0,"
                 Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Maybe you should switch the

Comment: Could you please post line 26 from MainPage.xaml?

Comment: hi Oleg,this is line 26: <TextBlock Text="my personal images" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0," Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, you're trying to set `12,-6,12,0,` as a thickness (probably a margin or a padding). Remove the trailing comma and it should work: `12,-6,12,0`

Comment: Hi KooKiz. thanks a lot. what u said is right. u r amazing. I am new to windows phone. If u don't mind please be in touch with me.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have the tag

`<StackPanel>`

opened two times and you closed only one of them

Comment: sorry Michael, i posted only one tag. but in the main program i closed it. The problem is not with the tag.